# Can you use .cub files in blender?

Tags: interface, add-on, edit-mode, coordinates, graph-editor

I am looking into a research opportunity with my college and my professor explained to me that he uses a application called Multiwfn and it produces a large txt file of coordinates, I was wondering if blender is able to process and coordinate the points to generate a 3-D model of the molecule we are researching. Multiwfn can also produce .cub files.
I my main question is, can blender handle a document being imported that has a large amount of coordinates?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Multiwfn](http://sobereva.com/multiwfn/)'s *.cub* files are formatted as described in *[Gaussian Cube Files](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/cube/)* by Paul Bourke.

There is an add-on [*Cube Blend*](https://github.com/funkymunkycool/cube_blend) available on GitHub that can read such files into blender.

The Add-on has not been updated in 4 years, so you may have some difficulty installing it, but the Git page points to a stack exchange discussion.

So yes, to answer your main question, Blender can handle a document with a large amount of coordinates.  How *well* Blender handles the document depends on how fast the processor is in your computer and how much memory you have available.

Comment: One probably could download an old version of Blender just to import the .cub file, save the .blend file and open in the newest version of Blender.